# How to fix display resolution issues on 2019 iMac 21.5in retina4k running 22.04

Tags: display, display-resolution, mac

Apple specs says the display runs at a 4096x2304 resolution. By default on a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 the maximum selectable resolution is 3840x2160. I edited the grub configuration file to set the display to run at Apple's published resolution @60hz and output looks like the attached image.

[image: attached image]

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Is there any available Additional Driver in `Software & Sources`?

Comment: Also restore the grub configuration to the default state